# How to use SciPy to optimize function with multiple constraints

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have three Pandas dataframes with the same columns as follow:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'A' : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 'B' : [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]], 'C' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}) 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'A' : ["a", "b", "c"], 'B' : [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]], 'C' : [30, 31, 32]}) 
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'A' : ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 'B' : [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]], 'C' : [50, 51, 52, 53]})
```

I have a fourth dataframe where the number of rows corresponds to the number of data frame I have, so here I have 3 rows then 3 dataframes.

```
dfZ = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'Z' : [1, 2, 3]})
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate a fourth column which is basically column C divided by the column B. 
I want one value per row to be chosen from the list of values in every row in column B. and that one value should be used for all the dataframes (meaning if I choose 0.5 for index 'a' then that value should be used for all dataframes with index 'a'. but the choice needs to satisfying these conditions

```
df1.sum() == dfZ['Z'].iloc[0] # tolerence 10 to 20%
df2.sum() == dfZ['Z'].iloc[1] # tolerence 10 to 20%
df2.sum() == dfZ['Z'].iloc[2] # tolerence 10 to 20%
```

Looking around it seems to be an optimization problem, but I have no idea how to use SciPy to solve it.

Comment: If i understood correctly and you want to optimize some partition / selection of indices, than this is an discrete-optimization problem and there is not much scipy can do for you. This looks more like some integer-programming problem and scipy has nothing to offer there. scipy's `Global Optimization` solvers could do something, but that would just be a hack.